# Const declaration of a function

Tags: c++, function, constants

What is the difference between these (in Const manner):

```
  const int getNum(int &a, int &b) const;

  const int getNum(int &a, int &b);

  int getNum(int &a, int &b) const;
```

Thank you!

Comment: All three are wrong: swap should return `void`.

Comment: changed it. its just an example.
and why is the downgrade?

Comment: @Itzik984 I guess (but I didn't downvote) because the code doesn't compile.

Comment: @Sjoerd its just for understanding, not compiling!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are member function declarations, presumably, not regular functions.

```
const int getNum(int &a, int &b) const;
```

The leftmost `const` means that the int being returned from this function is constant. This is a relatively meaningless distinction—sure, the int is constant, but you'll implicitly make a copy of it before using it. This *does* have an effect on class return types, but it's still not particularly useful.

The rightmost `const` means that the member function may be called on a constant object, and that the function is not allowed to modify the object. Effectively, the `this` pointer inside the function will be constant.

```
const int getNum(int &a, int &b);
```

The `const` here has the same meaning as the leftmost `const` in the first example—the return value is constant.

```
int getNum(int &a, int &b) const;
```

The `const` here has the same meaning as the rightmost `const` in the first example—the implicit `this` pointer is constant.

Answer (score 1):

```
const int swap(int &a, int &b);
```

returns an unchangeable value

```
  int swap(int &a, int &b) const;
```

returns changeable value, but inside it no one variable can be changed at runtime.

```
 const int swap(int &a, int &b) const;
```

the both

Answer (score 1):

The first and third are `const` member functions, meaning that they can be called on a `const` instance, and do not modify any of the instance's fields.

The first and second have return-type `const int`, which is not very useful, since they return a temporary value, so there's no point in making that value `const`.